# How can I create two numeric columns each containing one of the numbers in a character variable

Tags: r

```r
sum = c("40 Da + 12 Da de primes", "40 Da + 12 Da de primes", "50 Da", "50 Da", "50 Da")
```

How do I separate such a variable into the following columns:

| Price | Bonus |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | 12 |
| 40 | 12 |
| 50 | 0 |
| 50 | 0 |
| 50 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(sum) %>% 
   extract(sum, into = c("Price", "Bonus"),
      "^(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)?.*", convert = TRUE) %>% 
     mutate(Bonus = replace_na(Bonus, 0))
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  Price Bonus
  <int> <dbl>
1    40    12
2    40    12
3    50     0
4    50     0
5    50     0
```

#### data

```
sum = c("40 Da + 12 Da de primes", "40 Da + 12 Da de primes", "50 Da", "50 Da", "50 Da")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer, this worked beautifully.

Comment: I accepted the answer. Apparently I can't upvote answers yet since I haven't got enough reputation points. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the character vector is stored in a data.frame called `df`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    Price = as.numeric(coalesce(str_extract(sum, "^\\d+(?=\\sDa)"), "0")),
    Bonus = as.numeric(coalesce(str_extract(sum, "\\d+(?=\\sDa de primes)"), "0"))
    )
```

This returns

```r
                      sum Price Bonus
1 40 Da + 12 Da de primes    40    12
2 40 Da + 12 Da de primes    40    12
3                   50 Da    50     0
4                   50 Da    50     0
5                   50 Da    50     0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, this solution also works exactly as I needed.